# youtube api error

Tags: php, api, youtube

I have PHP loop that pulls video information from a specific playlist in a Youtube channel, but breaks when it encounters a private video. It gives a fatal error:

> Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in F:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\index.php on line 30
>
> Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in F:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\index.php on line 30
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in F:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\index.php on line 35

The code is below

```
<body>
<div id="mainPlayer" width="425" height="344">
</div>
</div>
<div id="mainPlaylist" class="grid_6 omega">
<h3 class="title">Legal Feed with Kate Wheeler</h3>
<ul id="playlists">
<?php
// Loop through each video in each playlist

    // read feed into SimpleXML object
    // *Moved into header to load main Video as well
$playlistFeedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/6549D4CA7BB99B16?v=2';
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($playlistFeedURL);
    
    // iterate over entries in feed
    foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
      // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
      $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
      
      // get video player URL
      $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
      $watch = $attrs['url'];
      
       
      
      // get video thumbnail
      $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
      $thumbnail = $attrs['url'];
            
      // get <yt:duration> node for video length
      $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
      $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
      $length = $attrs['seconds'];
      
      //get <yt:videoId> node for Video ID
      $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
      $playlistVideoID = $yt->videoid;
      
      
      // get <yt:stats> node for viewer statistics
      $yt = $entry->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
      $attrs = $yt->statistics->attributes();
      $viewCount = $attrs['viewCount'];
      
      // get <gd:rating> node for video ratings
      $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
      if ($gd->rating) {
        $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();
        $rating = $attrs['average'];  
      } else {
        $rating = 0;
      }
     
      
      ?>
      <div class="item">
          <span class="thumbnail left" rel="<?php echo $entry->id; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>" rel="<?php echo $playlistVideoID; ?>" onclick="_run();"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail;?>" /></a>
          </span>
             <a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>" rel="<?php echo $playlistVideoID; ?>" onclick="_run();"><?php echo $media->group->title; ?></a>
          <span class="attr">Duration:</span> <?php printf('%0.2f', $length/60); ?> min.
          <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>      
    <?php
    }
?>
</ul> 
</body>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: at least post the part of code that is related so that people can help you. or try something that may work and post the error messages.

Comment: It is normal for a feed to _not contain_ certain elements, e.g. rating fields will be missing if the uploader chose to disable ratings/like/dislikes. Check for the presence of node before attempting to read its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using DOM to pull apart the html from Youtube? kudos for that, but boo-hiss for assuming that all nodes are there at all times, e.g.

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('video');
$nodes[0]->attribute(....);  #<---but whatever if there's no video elements at all?


if ($nodes->length > 0) {
  $nodes[0]->attribute(...); #<--only does this if there was at least one video element
}
```

Comment: $playlistFeedURL = link';
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($playlistFeedURL);
    
    // iterate over entries in feed
    foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
      // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
      $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
      
      // get video player URL
      $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
      $watch = $attrs['url'];
   
    
      
      // get video thumbnail
      $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
      $thumbnail = $attrs['url'];

Comment: gah. don't put code blocks into comments. it's visual garbage. edit your question and put it there, using properly code formatting (highlight the code text, hit the `{}` button in the editor)